# Extract Values from terraform set variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am trying to provision aws service catalog product using terraform resource

```
resource "aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product" "example" {}
```

[Terraform resource output description](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/servicecatalog_provisioned_product#outputs)

one of the export value of the resource is **outputs** which is in form of set and i am collecting that into an output variable using below

```
output "Provisioned_Product_Outputs" {
  value = aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.example.outputs
}
```

**Output Looks Like**

```
Provisioned_Product_Outputs = toset([
  {
    "description" = "Backup plan"
    "key" = "BackupPlan"
    "value" = "light"
  },
  {
    "description" = "Current user zone to run"
    "key" = "CurrentAZ"
    "value" = "primary"
  },
  {
    "description" = "InstanceID of Vm"
    "key" = "EC2InstanceID"
    "value" = "i-04*******"
  },
  {
    "description" = "InstanceHostName"
    "key" = "InstanceHostName"
    "value" = "{\"fqdn\":\"foo.domain.com\"}"
  },
  {
    "description" = "The ARN of the launched Cloudformation Stack"
    "key" = "CloudformationStackARN"
    "value" = "arn:aws:cloudformation:{region}:{AccountID}:stack/SC-{AccountID}-pp-iy******"
  },
])
```

i would like to have only selected outputs values rather than entire set like below.

```
output "EC2InstanceID" {
  value = "i-04*******"
} 

output "InstanceHostName" {
  value = ""{\"fqdn\":\"foo.domain.com\"}""
}

output "CloudformationStackARN" {
  value =  "arn:aws:cloudformation:{region}:{AccountID}:stack/SC-{AccountID}-pp-iy******"
}
```

Is there a way to apply or have some condition which allows me to check for the right values using key value pair and apply the value in the outputs

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know that your output is `set`, you can create a filter on the objects inside the set using [`contains`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/contains):

```
output "outputs" {
  value = {
    for output in aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.example.outputs : output.key =>
    output.value if contains(["EC2InstanceID", "InstanceHostName", "CloudformationStackARN"], output.key)
  }
}
```

The output will be similar to this:

```
outputs = {
  "CloudformationStackARN" = "arn:aws:cloudformation:{region}:{AccountID}:stack/SC-{AccountID}-pp-iy******"
  "EC2InstanceID" = "i-04*******"
  "InstanceHostName" = "{\"fqdn\":\"foo.domain.com\"}"
}
```

If you want to have separate outputs, you have to type out each output manually:

```
output "EC2InstanceID" {
  value = [for output in aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.example.outputs : output.value if output.key == "EC2InstanceID"][0]
}

output "InstanceHostName" {
  value = [for output in aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.example.outputs : output.value if output.key == "InstanceHostName"][0]
}

output "CloudformationStackARN" {
  value = [for output in aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.example.outputs : output.value if output.key == "CloudformationStackARN"][0]
}
```

You can not have a `for_each` attribute for outputs. Currently `resource` and `module` blocks support `for_each` attributes.

Comment: Hi Ervin, Thanks for you kind help on the question this will certainly bring me closure  the expected output. Can this be use to have each value a separate output rather than single block.  Like one i have pasted in required output

```
output "EC2InstanceID" {
  value = "i-04*******"
} 
```

Comment: You can not have a `for_each` for an output. You will have to create a separate output for each key-value, this can not be done conditionally.

Comment: Hi Ervin, you mean to say like below

```
output "EC2InstanceID" {
  value = {
    for output in aws_servicecatalog_provisioned_product.example.outputs : output.key =>
    output.value if contains(["EC2InstanceID"], output.key)
  }
}
```

Comment: I meant the [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta argument.

Comment: Hi Ervin, thanks very much but could you please share an example with for_each as i am new to terraform i am not able to understand the context here . I am referring to "You can not have a for_each for an output. You will have to create a separate output for each key-value, this can not be done conditionally."

Comment: Updated my answer. I can not give an example for `for_each` because outputs can NOT have for_each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244351/discussion-between-mahi-and-ervin-szilagyi).